# Should VLANs and AD match organizational chart for implementing 802.1x with Dynamic VLAN?

Tags: active-directory, vlan, architecture, 802.1x

I am experiencing an issue while trying to understand the best way to implement 802.1x (EAP Chaining with AD as the identity service) in a corporate environment. The following questions have arisen during the planning of the implementation for the entire company:

1. Is Dynamic VLAN assignment commonly used in large environments? If so, should all VLANs be configured on all access switches?
2. Should each department have its own separate VLAN for segregation?
3. Should AD users be grouped based on the company's organizational chart?

Essentially, I am trying to determine if it's worth to restructure the AD and VLANs to align with the organizational chart in order to implement ISE policies.

Thank you!

Comment: It depends. Do you have cloud services? Does all services have strong authentication? What risk evaluations do you have? What do you gain from segregating? Does users move between switches, or are they assigned to one physical place? Does department segregations make sense? Does everyone access the same resources anyway? There's a lot of leg work *you* have to do to figure out what's right in your scenario.